# Seeking advice on performance metrics based on NewRelic dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, apache-2.4, django, performance-tuning

Some background:

I have been given access to our newrelic dashboard for the production servers running a django app on an AWS account, and tasked to come up with some gatling.io (performance testing software) scripts.

The reason for this is that I have uncovered a major problem with our apache config, and tested my config on the dev box, and saw a drastic improvement in memory and CPU consumption.  We now want to create scripts against parts of the application which are performing poorly, such that after we change the config for production, we can re-measure them and find out how much of an improvement this new config truly is.

The problem at hand:

I have too much information on newrelic:

```
Transactions
    Most time consuming transactions by percentage
    Routes with slowest average response times
    Top transactions with highest wall clock time
Database
    same as above
```

My question is where should I narrow my focus?  I can't create scripts for everything, so where can/should I begin in order to provide an accurate display of the new config working properly?  How do I choose the number of users of each request, as well as the scaling of those users based on the information in newrelic?  Any and all information is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're running your environment on AWS, I'm hoping that you're environment is setup using CloudFormation templates or any of the services built upon it (e.g. Elastic Beanstalk). With that assumption, I'm gonna propose the following:

1. Spin up an exact copy of your environment in a separate VPC
2. Create your load test scripts, starting with a lower amount of requests and increasing to a level which you have during peak hours.
3. Run your load test script against your cloned environment with the old configs during e.g. 1 hour
4. Do your config changes in the cloned environment (or for that sake, take down the clone and spin up a new one with the changes)
5. Run the same load test script against the new config changes for the same amount of time

As for *what* to test, I would focus on the endpoints which normally has the highest load and/or the heaviest ones. These are the ones where you will see the difference most clearly.

When later on doing the comparison in New Relic, compare response times on transactions, cpu, memory etc.

Comment: thanks for the input.  I found that if I do an App histogram on the routes consuming the most amount of time, I can get a number of requests at that point of time.  I found an increase in requests over 1.5 hours from 25 to 401 on the home page, causing a serious delay in response time.  How do I covert this metric over to a span of minutes?  Or should I rather keep the same ratio of 1.5 hours?  BTW: we have a mirror of our prod servers on two different environments.  staging and performance.  I was planning my tests against those

Comment: @SamHammamy: I'm not really sure what you mean, but as long as you look at the same time intervall when you compare before and after you should be fine.